# Sum of the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I need to show that the sum of the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} = \frac{2}{27}(18+\sqrt{3}\pi)$. However, I don't know how to start, since this series does not fit a power series, and I can't find a rearrangement that makes the series a known power series. How can I do this?

Comment: The absurdly specific result makes me think finding a way to manipulate known series involving $\pi$ might help. What is the context here?

Comment: See [this paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/g27/g27.pdf) esp if you're familiar with generating functions.